# C .data initialization and .bss clearing

Tags: c, startup, boot

Little background:

I am working on a RISC-V processor that I laid out the memory for personally (its on an FPGA), and what I did was put the program memory and constant data in the on board flash.  I wrote my own custom `_start` routine, which is supposed to copy the `.data` initial contents from flash to RAM and clear the `.bss` section.

Is there any way for me to verify that my `_start` routine works (I have gotten lights blinking but I am not confident in this test)?

Comment: Do you have the ability to examine the memory, e.g. with a debugger or JTAG?

Comment: @hellow No I don't.....I have been researching looking into that......but suppose I did (I am willing to upgrade my tool set)

Comment: Simply spew out the whole of `.data` on your favourite serial bus?

Comment: @Lundin In essence that is what my test program currently does (it blinks the contents on a bunch of LEDs)

Comment: If you are serious with fpga development, you should look into tools like Intel Quartus (former Altera) or Xilinx ISE, which have an in-system memory inspector allowing you to examine and modify memory  blocks you configure.

Answer (score 0):

You should look in the bootrom and make sure that it starts to read memory, then in the crt file(if you need them) you need to specify a link to the procedure for starting the program, for example, to _start or _main. Аlso you need build structure of section in linker script link.ld like this:

```
OUTPUT_ARCH( "riscv" )
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
  . = 0x80000000;
  .text.init : { *(.text.init) }
  . = ALIGN(0x1000);
  .tohost : { *(.tohost) }
  . = ALIGN(0x1000);
  .text : { *(.text) }
  . = ALIGN(0x1000);
  .data : { *(.data) }
  .bss : { *(.bss) }
  _end = .;
}
```

And compile it alltogether:`riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc hello.c crt.S -Tlink.ld -o hello.riscv`. Also you can only use bootrom, for example:

```
#define RAM_BASE 0x80000000

.section .text.start, "ax", @progbits
.globl _start
_start:
  j _hang

.section .text.hang, "ax", @progbits
.globl _hang
_hang:
  li s0, RAM_BASE
  csrr a0, mhartid
  la a1, _dtb
  jr s0

.section .rodata.dtb, "a", @progbits
.globl _dtb
.align 5, 0
_dtb:
.ascii "DTB goes here"
```

And use simple assembler program without any _start or _main or something else, just old good asm codes.

Anyway you can look examples at:
https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tests